# signalr - TypeError: chat is undefined

Tags: javascript, .net, signalr, real-time

Estoy desarrollando un *chat* simple con `signalr` y me he topado con un error que aún no logro resolver.

[image: Captura del error]

Dice que la variable `chat` no está definida lo cual no es cierto, ya que yo la estoy declarando.

```
var chat = $.connection.chat;

$(function () {
    chat.client.nuevoMensaje = onNewMessage;
    $.connection.hub.start();
});

function onNewMessage(message) {
    chat.server.enviarMensaje("hola");
};
```

He agregado todas la referencias requeridas.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Este es el Hub que he creado del lado del servidor.

```
[HubName("Chat")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void EnviarMensaje(string mensaje)
    {
        var msg = string.Format("{0} {1}", Context.ConnectionId, mensaje);
        Clients.All.nuevoMensaje(msg);
    }

    public void UnirSala(string sala)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, sala);
    }

    public void EnviarMensajeSala(string sala, string mensaje)
    {
        var msg = string.Format("{0} {1}", Context.ConnectionId, mensaje);
        Clients.Group(sala).nuevoMensaje(msg);
    }

    public void EnviarMensajeData(EnviarData data)
    {
        Clients.All.nuevaData(data);
    }


    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        EnviarDataAMonitor("Conectado", Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        EnviarDataAMonitor("Desconectado", Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        EnviarDataAMonitor("Reconexción", Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

    private void EnviarDataAMonitor(string typoEvento, string connectionId)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MonitorHub>();
        context.Clients.All.nuevoEvento(typoEvento, connectionId);
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe el por qué del error, sabiendo que ya he declarado la variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ya encontre el problema!

Cuando estaba editando mi pregunta, me encontraba probando una posible solución.

El nombre del `hub` se lo estaba pasando mal.
Del lado del servidor el script automático que se generaba tenia como nombre `Chat` pero en el cliente lo estaba llamando `chat`.

**Hub**

```
[HubName("Chat")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    .......
```

**Código Cliente**

```
var chat = $.connection.chat;
```

En este caso existen dos soluciones, o bien, cambiar el nombre del Hub, o cambiar el llamado en el código cliente.

**Cambiando el Hub**

```
[HubName("chat")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    .....
```

**Cambiando el código cliente**

```
var chat = $.connection.Chat;
```

Cualquiera de estos dos casos son validos, lo importante es que el nombre del `hub` se llame igual en el lado del cliente, si el nombre del `hub` es `mensaje` el llamado en javascript debería ser `$.connection.mensaje;`

Answer (score 1):

La única explicación que se me ocurre es que `$.connection.chat` devuelve `undefined` y se asigna a tu variable `chat` por lo cual en la sgte línea da error

Comment: Gracias!,tienes razón ``$.connection.chat`` devuelve ``undefined``, ahora tengo que mirar el por que devuelve ese error, eh agregado mas detalles. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La variable *chat* está fuera de *scope* en el método *onNewMessage* y por eso te dice que no está definida.

Yo movería la función *onNewMessage* dentro del *document.ready()* de jQuery, es decir:

```
$(function () {
    var chat = $.connection.chat;
    chat.client.nuevoMensaje = onNewMessage;
    $.connection.hub.start();

    function onNewMessage(message) {
      chat.server.enviarMensaje("hola");
   };

});
```

Comment: Hola, ya saque la variable ``chat`` del scope por que era mas conveniente para mi de esta manera, pero aun así sigue el error, ya agregue mas detalles a la pregunta.

Comment: No se refiere a la línea de `chat.server` sino a `chat.client`

Comment: si, lo entiendo pero no me conviene dejar ningún método por ahora en el scope del Ready() por cuestiones personales. y en ``chat.server`` no esta dando error aun, el error es en el llamado del hub, pero ya resolví :) mil gracias por sus aportes.